# make block with dynamic height vertically scrollable

Tags: css

`<div>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
         ....
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>`

here i have a `<div>` block with `<h2>`, `<p>`, and `<ul>` with a lot of `<li>`'s. I set div's height to 100%, to make it fit the window's height(through absolute positioning, or any other way). The task is to make ul fit all the free space inside the div (no div stretching) and be vertically scrollable. It is easy if we set ul's height to fixed number or relative %, BUT it should be adjusted if the window's, p or h2 height changes. I need an adaptive solution, ul should always fit even if window is resized or new content is added to p or h2, and have scrollable content.

Comment: something with `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: yes, something with overflow: scroll, that works usually on blocks with fixed height. I need it to work on a block that has an adaptive height. % height is not the case here

Comment: If you just *don't* define the height of the childrens elements? Then of course it sometimes will be too short if not enough content to fill the `div`, but if there was more it would be scrollable...